# Android compose button spacing with long text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this view on my android app using jetpack compose, as we can see, I have 5 buttons with long and short text.
I wonder why there is no spacing between the 2 long text button, but when a single line button has I think 4.dp padding both top and bottom?
[5 buttons screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT9x2.png)

I have this code for that view:

```
@Composable
private fun HomeBody(onNextButtonClicked: () -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.long_text))
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.long_text))
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.short_button))
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.short_button))
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.long_text))
        }
    }
}
```

And called as scaffold body:

```
HomeBody({}, Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize())
```

I am expecting a fixed spacing between each buttons regardless if the text is multiple line or single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `verticalArrangment` property of `Column` composable to space the items evenly.

```
Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp) // set to whatever you want
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {},
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.long_text),
                Modifier
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 40.dp) // set to atleast 40dp
                    .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            )
        }
}
```

The uneven spacing issue, is due to the fact the Material Design enforces some rules, so they have set the minimum height of the `Button` to be `40dp`, so that the users can easily click it.

Now, when the contents of the button have height less than `40dp`. The background color wraps to the content, but the container's height is still `40dp`.

So you can explicitly set the minimum height of the contents in this case the `Text` composable to `40dp` so that background color will also extend to those.

`wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)` use this to vertically center the text after the height is changed.

If you need padding and top of first button and bottom of last button you can specify them using the padding of First and Last Button modifier.

[image]

Comment: I see, that's how we use "spacedBy", I just wonder why the spacing between the 2 buttons with short text is a little bit larger than the long text buttons? Is there a way to make it fixed regardless of the button text length?

Comment: Hi, I have update the answer. Do upvote and set the answer as accepted if found helpful.

Comment: I got my expected results now, but is it mandatory to add minHeight = 40.dp to a button content? for a single liner text, the button got taller to 40.dp.

Comment: Yes, I have explained the reason in my answer. It is enforced by material design. Earlier, also the button was 40dp, only the background color was filled to the content, so we thought that there is extra space but in reality it was the button only. See the source code of the Button by (CMD + B) or (Ctrl + B) and go through   the source code of Button you will see that minimum height is set to 40.dp

Answer (score 0):

Let our background color be white, and the color of our `Column` be red. Now, let's consider this with the following three examples. The point you missed here is that you are actually applying `padding` to the `Column`. Here, we observe that as the `padding` value increases, the white `background` also expands. If the contents inside cannot accommodate the `padding`, they get compressed. Because the `buttons` inside have a `contentPadding` and they want to adapt the text inside to this `padding` value too. The reason why your expectations are not met here is because of this compression. If there is enough screen space, compression will not occur, and the paddings of the `buttons` will be displayed correctly. I hope these three examples should be sufficient for you.

So, the right approach is to add `Spacer` between `buttons` or do this with ready made such as `spacedBy`.

```
object ButtonDefaults {

    private val ButtonHorizontalPadding = 24.dp
    private val ButtonVerticalPadding = 8.dp

    val ContentPadding =
        PaddingValues(
            start = ButtonHorizontalPadding,
            top = ButtonVerticalPadding,
            end = ButtonHorizontalPadding,
            bottom = ButtonVerticalPadding
        )

    private val ButtonWithIconHorizontalStartPadding = 16.dp
}
```

Here are the paddings of the contents inside the buttons.

And Examples:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 600, heightDp = 300)
modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Red)
```

[image]

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 300, heightDp = 500)
modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Red)
```

[image]

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, widthDp = 300, heightDp = 500)
modifier = Modifier.padding(70.dp).fillMaxSize().background(color = Color.Red)
```

[image]